# ¿Como puedo ocupar los datos que obtengo de un texbox en todo el form?

Tags: c#, .net

¿Como puedo ocupar los datos que obtengo de un texbox en todo el form si tener que repetir la declaración de una variable en cada evento de diferentes botones en C#, por ejemplo tengo dos botones, pero no quiero declarar dos veces la variable nombre, como puedo hacer esto, soy novata y quiero ir mejorando mi codigo, gracias

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ADULTOS
{
    public partial class familiar : Form
    {
      string curp = tb_curp.Text; //es el texbox

        public familiar()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }

        private void familiar_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            cb_pa.DataSource = Model.ObtenerParentesco(); //llenamos el combo
            Console.WriteLine(cb_pa.DataSource);
            cb_pa.DisplayMember = "nombre_p";
            cb_pa.ValueMember = "parentesco_id";
        }

        bool validarTextBoxs()
        {
            foreach (Control item in this.Controls)
            {
                try
                {
                    if (item is TextBox)
                    {
                        //Codigo comprobacion  de textbox
                        if (item.Text == "")
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show("Hay campos vacios", "ATENCIÓN", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
                            item.Focus();
                            return false;
                        }
                    }
                    else if (item is RichTextBox)
                    {
                        //codigo comprobacion de richtextbox
                        if (item.Text == "")
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show("Hay campos vacios");
                            item.Focus();
                            return false;
                        }
                    }
                    else if (item is ComboBox)
                    {
                        if (item.Text == "")
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show("Debes seleccionar un item");
                            item.Focus();
                            return false;
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch { }
            }
            return true;
        }


        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OpenFileDialog openUrlImg = new OpenFileDialog();
            openUrlImg.Filter = "All supported graphics|*.jpg;*.jpeg;*.png|" +
                                "JPEG (*.jpg;*.jpeg)|*.jpg;*.jpeg|" +
                                "Portable Network Graphic (*.png)|*.png";
            openUrlImg.Title = "Seleccionar una imagen";
            try
            {
                if (openUrlImg.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    if (openUrlImg.FileName.Equals("") == false)
                    {
                        l_foto_f.Text = openUrlImg.FileName;
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("No se puede cargar imagen: " + ex.ToString(), "ATENCIÓN", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
        }



        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            if (validarTextBoxs())
            {

            }

        }

        private void btn_con_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

declara tu variable por fuera de los metodos para que sean globales

```
  string nombre= textBox1.Text;

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {

               // aca ya podes usar nombre

            }

     private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {

               // aca ya podes usar nombre

            }
```

Comment: Hola @Bruno con esto me dice en vs que un inicializador de campo no puede hacer referencia al campo, método o propiedad no estáticos de mi form.textBox1, si lo pongo en cada click, me lo toma bien

Comment: agrega toda la clase en tu pregunta por favor

Comment: ya y disculpa la molestia

Answer (score 2):

Como te dijo Bruno debes instanciar tu variable nombre de forma global y no dentro del evento click del botón, además debes hacerlo dentro de la clase principal, seguramente lo estás haciendo por fuera de este y por eso te da ese error

```
public partial class TuClase...
```